# Duda con usuario e e-mail en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, nodejs, callback

tengo un inconveniente con este ejercicio, el cual trata los temas sobre los callbacks, tengo una función principal, la cual se llama "constructor" y recibe 3 parámetros, el primero de ellos es un identificador con valor número, los otros dos son los callbacks, se me hizo más fácil nombrarlos "f" para hacer referencia a la palabra reservada función.

Dentro de constructor hago una búsqueda en el array de objetos llamado "usuario" utilizando la función find(), dicha búsqueda compara si el valor obtenido por find() es exactamente igual al valor ingresado al momento de invocar a la función "constructor", después se evalúa si dicho valor existe y se procede a invocar el primer callback, que dependiendo del valor obtenido se ejecuta más de una ocasión, hasta este momento me debe devolver el nombre del usuario.

Lo mismo se debería aplicar para el callback número 2, el cual se nombro como "f2", pero en esta ocasión debería mostrar la dirección de e-mail correspondiente al id del usuario, pero solo me muestra la segunda condicional, la cual dice "El correo electrónico no existe".

De antemano gracias por el apoyo.

```
var usuario=[
        {
            nombre:'Doribel',
            edad:35,
            id:1
        }
    ];

    var correo=[
        {
            id:1,
            email:'doribelpenagos@gmail.com'
        }
    ];

    var constructor=function(id,f,f2){
        
        let respuesta=usuario.find((valorUsuario) => valorUsuario.id===id);


        if(respuesta===id){
            f();
        }else{
            f(respuesta);
        }

        //-----------------------------------------

        let respuestaCorreo=correo.find(function(valorCorreo){
            let respuestaCorreo=(valorCorreo.id===id);
            return(respuestaCorreo);
        });

        let evaluar=(respuesta.id===respuestaCorreo.id);

        if(evaluar){
            f2();
        }else{
            f2(respuestaCorreo);
        }
    }

    constructor(1,function(valorUsuario){
        if(valorUsuario){
            alert('Usuario '+valorUsuario.nombre);
        }else{
            alert('El usuario no existe');
        }
    },function(valorCorreo){
        if(valorCorreo){
            alert('El correo del usuario es '+valorCorreo.email);
        }else{
            alert('El correo electrónico no existe ');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hice una version modificada, fijate si te da el resultado esperado. Basicamente si el id recibido en contructor() existe dentro de "usuario" o "correo" muestra alguno de los 2 o ambos si tienen el mismo id como es en tu ejemplo.

```
var usuario=[{ nombre:'Doribel', edad:35, id:1 }]
var correo=[{ id:1, email:'doribelpenagos@gmail.com' }]

function constructor(id,f,f2){
   if(usuario[0].id==id)  f(true)
   else f(false)
   f2(id);
}

constructor(1,function f(existe){
    if(existe) console.log("nombre encontrado!: " + usuario[0].nombre)
    else console.log("el nombre no existe!");
},function f2(id){
    if(id == correo[0].id) console.log("mail encontrado!: " + correo[0].email);
    else console.log("el correo no existe!")
});
```

un consejo: estas declarando usuario y correo como arrays con objetos lo que es innecesario porque son arrays con 1 elemento y ese elemento es el objeto, es mejor y mas facil simplemente declarar como objeto por ej:

```
const usuario = { nombre:'Doribel', edad:35, id:1 }
```

Pero en este ejemplo lo dejo como lo declaraste tu. Si correo y usuario tienen id's diferentes mostrara el que coincida con el parametro numerico pasado a la funcion "constructor". Si no coincide usuario o correo muestra mensajes de error.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por el apoyo brindado, la lógica que propones me da una nueva perspectiva de como poder resolver problemas futuros, en verdad gracias, valoro tu esfuerzo y el tiempo que dedicaste a formular esta solución, que tengas un buen día, de antemano te envío un cordial saludo.